# How to test equality for a sublist in java, Mockito

Tags: java, list, mockito, java.util.concurrent, sublist

I have a method that has a collection as an argument:

```
call(Collection<String> strings);
```

I am calling the method as follows:

```
myClass.call(list.sublist(1,n));
```

Everything is running perfectly when I am running the code.
However, when testing with Mockito, I am testing it using the code snippet:

```
verify(myClass,times(1)).call(myList);
```

it is repeatedly throwing the following error:

> Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'java.util.ConcurrentModificationException' exception.

I am guessing this is because it is unable to cast to test. Any workarounds that can help? I wany to check if myList contains same elements as those passed.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with casting. Can you share a fuller snippet? You haven't given us too much to go on.

Comment: This is all the info that I have honestly.

Comment: What I mean with casting is that I tried debugging with argument matcher but the debugger cannot evaluate the object passed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]; anything else is pure speculation on our side; and thus a waste of everybody time and energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually, the verify method is called after the whole function has run.

So even though myClass had correct sublist as a parameter when called, the sublist becomes invalid when list is modified later.

Verify method is called after the whole method is called, so the sublist to be tested at the time of validation is invalid.

Hence it was throwing that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use a @Captor and add Hamcrest to your project and do this...

```
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<Collection<String>> collectionCaptor;

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception
    {
        Collection<String> expectedCollection = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"); 

        // setup goes here
        // execute test

        Mockito.verify(myClass).call(collectionCaptor.capture());
        Collection<String> whatWasCaptured = collectionCaptor.getValue();
        assertThat(whatWasCaptured, Matchers.containsInAnyOrder(expectedCollection));
    }
}
```

Also make sure that your collection is not mutating in other threads. If you can't control what other threads are doing then you should be coding defensively and returning `return Collections.unmodifiableList(myList)` or switching your data structure to one that supports [immutablility like Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)